# Change width of DataTemplate dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have this ListView with a custom DataTemplate:

```
<ListView Name="lvDataBinding" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,200,0,30" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <templates:ZoneTemplate Name="dataTemplate"  Margin="-5,0,-5,0" Width="160"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to change dynamically (from C#) the width of the DataTemplate. I tried `Data Binding` for `Width` parameters but it doesn't seems to work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you try to bind `Width`? And what `Snoop` or visual studio's `output` shows for binding, is there any errors?

Comment: `<templates:ZoneTemplate Name="dataTemplate"  Margin="-5,0,-5,0" Width="{Binding TemplateWidth}"/>
` Then I tried to set it from .cs file but wont work. No errors.

Comment: Did your ListViewItem's viewmodels have a TemplateWidth property?

Comment: Yes. But it won't work. It's getting random size (same behaviour when Width is not set)

Comment: You problem at item that you use for in `DataTemplate`, check `ZoneTemplate` why it's not resize due to your binding. Just and small sample without your template and it works fine.

Comment: ZoneTemplate is an xaml without any logic in CS. I think the problem is not there because if I change the width in  ` <templates:ZoneTemplate Name="dataTemplate"  Margin="-5,0,-5,0" Width="160"/>` it works as expected. It just not work with DataBinding

Comment: you can set `HorizontalContentAlignment` directly on `ListView`. Any reason to have it in the ItemContainerStyle?

Comment: How did you bind your Width exactly?  Currently it seems to not be using any Binding

Comment: Not any specific reason for HorizontalCA I move it to the ListView. `<templates:ZoneTemplate Name="dataTemplate" Margin="-5,0,-5,0" Width="{Binding TemplateWidth}"/>` Then I tried to set it from .cs file but wont work

Comment: Are you implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface? Are you properly firing the PropertyChanged event? Do you get any binding errors in the debug output?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how did you populate you list, and which VM you use, so I made some work around as an example:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <ListView Name="lvDataBinding" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,200,0,30" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Fill="AntiqueWhite" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"
                       Height="50"
                       Name="dataTemplate" 
                       Margin="-5,0,-5,0"
                       Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                AncestorType=Window}, Path=ItemWidth}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
  </ListView>
  <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},
    Path=ItemWidth}"/>
</Grid>
```

And in the cs file of this window:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ItemWidth", typeof (int), typeof (MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(170));

    public int ItemWidth
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(ItemWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemWidthProperty, value); }
    }
```